Can't proxy request from one container to another using nginx
I've got an api running on 8000th port in a container, and I'm trying to proxy requests from 80th port to this api. Nginx is also running in a separate container. So, when I enter http://localhost:80 in my web browser I only get starting page of nginx.
docker-compose.yml
services:
  rust-warp:
    build: ./fast-test-rust
    container_name: rust-warp
    restart: unless-stopped
  rust-warp-nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: rust-warp-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf.prod:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - rust-warp

Dockerfile in a rust API
FROM rust:1.70

COPY ./ ./

RUN cargo build --release

CMD ["./target/release/fast-test-rust"]

docker logs rust-warp
Running on 8000 port

docker logs rust-warp-nginx
rust-warp-nginx  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
rust-warp-nginx  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
rust-warp-nginx  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
rust-warp-nginx  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: IPv6 listen already enabled
rust-warp-nginx  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
rust-warp-nginx  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
rust-warp-nginx  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
rust-warp-nginx  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up

2024/08/30 09:49:10 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2024/08/30 09:49:10 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.27.1
2024/08/30 09:49:10 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14) 
2024/08/30 09:49:10 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 6.10.0-linuxkit
2024/08/30 09:49:10 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2024/08/30 09:49:10 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2024/08/30 09:49:10 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 22
2024/08/30 09:49:10 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 23
2024/08/30 09:49:10 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 24
2024/08/30 09:49:10 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 25
2024/08/30 09:49:10 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 26
2024/08/30 09:49:10 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 27
2024/08/30 09:49:10 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 28
2024/08/30 09:49:10 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 29
192.168.65.1 - - [30/Aug/2024:09:49:14 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
2024/08/30 09:49:14 [error] 22#22: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.65.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
192.168.65.1 - - [30/Aug/2024:09:49:14 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.65.1 - - [30/Aug/2024:09:49:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.65.1 - - [30/Aug/2024:09:49:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.65.1 - - [30/Aug/2024:09:49:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.65.1 - - [30/Aug/2024:09:49:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.65.1 - - [30/Aug/2024:09:49:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.65.1 - - [30/Aug/2024:09:49:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.65.1 - - [30/Aug/2024:09:49:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.65.1 - - [30/Aug/2024:09:49:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.65.1 - - [30/Aug/2024:09:49:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.65.1 - - [30/Aug/2024:09:49:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"

I've tried to change directories, volume paths. I tried to add '/' in location path, tried to add headers using proxy_set_header.
And as I can see in logs, nginx gets my requests from browser but it doesn't proxy these requests and I don't see any errors.

You need to add your nginx config to the question for folks to not need to guess what the problem is :).

Based on your log output it looks like you're referencing your service with localhost in your nginx.conf. This won't work because the "localhost" on the nginx container is local to the inside of the container and does not reference your machine's localhost. In other words, while http://localhost:8000 may resolve in your browser, it will not resolve inside the nginx container.
To reference another service hosted via dockercompose, you should use http://[SERVICE NAME] which in your case would be http://rust-warp. You may or may not need to specify the port, depending on your configuration (http://rust-warp:8000), and/or specify port configuration in your dockercompose file for your rust-warp service.
Here's more info on how networking works in dockercompose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
